# Elasticsearch and Splunk connection via Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, splunk

I am currently experimenting with a company that has their log data in elasticsearch. (They currently use the entire ELK stack).

Splunk has a plugin called Hunk that lets you query HDFS / Hadoop data from Splunk's interface.  I have been able to get this working.

My question is, is there a way using es-hadoop to somehow 'bridge' the two together?  That when Hunk queries my hdfs, it also will end up pulling in the Elasticsearch data?

(They company wants to see if its feasible to use Splunk without having to duplicate the data)

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked into logstash? Though, why use Splunk at all?

Comment: They use the whole ELK stack, I'll clarify that.  They want to experiment with Splunk, but without duplicating the data.

Comment: Gotcha. Unfortunately, I believe Hunk strictly searches HDFS data. The connector between ES and Hadoop is only one way from HDFS to ES

Comment: So the only obvious solution here would be that all log data should be stored in the HDFS, then accessed as necessary by the connectors?

Comment: Without personal experience using Splunk / Hunk, that is how I typically have seen data stored. Alternative solution would be to split the data at the log source, then feed into both Hadoop and ElasticSearch, but as you said, you don't want to duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Splunk deprecated HUNK in 2016, and released Hadoop Connect. Now you can read, write, explore, and export from HDFS. There is no Splunk license fee associated with reading, writing, or exploring HDFS clusters. So you can work with data from HDFS to create statistical solutions without incurring a fee. Splunk's betting that you'll want to put summarized data as well as refined data sets into Splunk to make them more available to enterprise audiences. https://www.splunk.com/blog/2012/12/20/connecting-splunk-and-hadoop/